# Can I start 2 simultaneous workout sessions on Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, healthkit, watchos-4

I would like to start 2 simultaneous workout sessions on my Apple watch app.  Per the docs it only looks like I can have one session running at a time, but does anyone know of a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no workaround. Only one app may be recording a workout at a time.